# PostGIS and QGIS - how to restrict delete, add, rename layer

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgadmin-4

How do I restrict users from deleting, adding, or renaming the layers from my database? or would it be possible to only show the project but not the layers?

Note: I logged in to my superuser account, but I have another user for public usage.

[image]

Comment: Only an owner can do that, which is why you don't let random users connect as the owner.  This is more basic database administration than a GIS issue.

Comment: Thanks, Vince, I used another computer to login as a public user. Yeah, public users can't delete or add nor rename my tables as a public user.

Comment: I believe an answer describing what is within QGIS and what is part of PostGIS could be useful - particularly for newer QGIS/PostGIS-user.